# click_link not working with PhantomJS 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, turbolinks

After upgrading PhantomJS to v2 and Poltergeist to v1.9.0 click_link("Text") is not work anymore.

The app is using Turbolinks.

When I take screenshots before and after it seems like the link was clicked and Turbolinks progress bar is making progress but href is never reached.

It was working before.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context, HTML, test code, etc... Before anyone will be able to give suggestions

Answer (score 1):

This bug does not occur with Phantom 1.9.x, so I suggest that you switch back from Phantom 2 to Phantom 1.9. This worked for me.

Comment: that's what we did actually.

Comment: @PieterVandenheede How is this not an answer? It states that a solution is to switch back to Phantom 1.9 - not a workaround, but it solves the problem.